# String replace using concatenated strings from various columns

Tags: postgresql, update, pattern-matching

I'd like to remove a substring in a column via update statement. The substring to replace consists of multiple strings from other different columns but in strict order.

The specification says:

> replace(string text, from text, to text)

Example:

```
field1                     |field2       |field3      |field4 
---------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------
(varchar)bla abla 123 ooops|(varchar)abla|(varchar)123|(varchar) ooops
```

The substring to replace consists of strings in field2, field3, field4 and blanks between field2 and field3, field3 and field4. In the given example: "abla 123 ooops".

So, after performing the update statement field1 should *only* contain the string "bla".

Note: I want to perform this on all rows and not to a particular one.

Comment: You should provide your version of Postgres with every question. You should also provide the table definition. For one, this would tell us whether your columns can be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you would want to deal with possible NULL values, [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is probably your safest and simplest way to go:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET filed1 = replace(field1, concat_ws(' ', field2, field3, field4), '')
WHERE filed1 IS DISTINCT FROM replace(field1, concat_ws(' ', field2, field3, field4), '')
```

`concat_ws()` ignores `NULL` values. With plain concatenation (`||`), one `NULL` field would make the whole pattern `NULL`. It was introduced with Postgres 9.1.

The added `WHERE` clause prevents empty updates. This enhances performance a lot if many rows wouldn't change anyway.