# PostgreSQL full text search on many columns

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I need an advice with searching of record based on specified string.

Search strings can contain values from these columns. Values in this string don´t have to be strictly identical given in the correct order and also the values of some columns in this string may be missing.

Example of search string:

```
22 Karntner Wien
```

And I get for example result with top 5 similar records.

I think I should use full text search, but I have no experiences with it. Can you tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest this expression for query and index:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', immutable_concat_ws(' ', country, city, street, house_nr, postcode))
    @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', '22 Kärntner Wien');
```

Note the custom function **`immutable_concat_ws()`**. `concat_ws()` is only `STABLE`, not **`IMMUTABLE`**. Create this function *first*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT array_to_string($2, $1)';
```

Or as "standard SQL" function in Postgres 14+. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN array_to_string($2, $1);
```

It's a drop-in replacement for [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), except that it only takes text input, which allows us to make it `IMMUTABLE` without cheating, effectively. Passing non-immutable input (with explicit cast to `text`) would void this warranty! Detailed explanation (read it!):

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860)

About `VARIADIC`:

- [Passing multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115702/939860)

**Or**, if you you have **superuser** privileges, see:

- [Create an immutable clone of concat_ws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384767/939860)

For ***many*** columns, this is shorter and faster. You *could* do without it but then the syntax gets rather verbose (see [joanolo's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164019/3684)).

The matching index to go with this:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_adr_fts_idx ON tbl USING GIN (
       to_tsvector('simple', immutable_concat_ws(' ', country, city, street, house_nr, postcode)));
```

You are dealing with international address data, so do *not* use the `english` text search configuration. Stemming makes little sense for *names*  and most of your example data is not even English to begin with. Use the `simple` configuration instead. You need the form with two parameters - see below.

Concatenate the strings and call the more expensive function `to_tsvector()` *once*. Use `concat_ws()` to deal with possible NULL values elegantly. Cheaper overall, and also shorter.

- [String replace using concatenated strings from various columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42241/string-replace-using-concatenated-strings-from-various-columns/42243#42243)

Like I commented, Full Text Search has limited support for fuzzy matching, but there is the often overlooked feature of prefix matching:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column/157982#157982)

So, if you are not sure whether it's *'Kärntner'* or *'Kärnten'*, and whether it's *'Straße'*, *'strasse'* or *'Strabe'* (like in your buggy example data) but you know that the second word follows the first, you could:

```
... @@ to_tsquery('simple', '22 & Kärnt:* <-> Stra:* & Wien')
```

`<->` is the phrase search operator and requires Postgres **9.6**.

- [How to store short stories for access to individual sentences?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161078/how-to-store-short-stories-for-access-to-individual-sentences/161116#161116)

And if you want to ignore diacritical signs as well (*'ä'* <> *'a'*), add `unaccent()` to the mix. You can use it as separate *function* or you can add it as [***dictionary***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html) to your text search configuration. You need to install the extension first ...

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

Overview over pattern matching option in typical Postgres installations:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

[Joanolo already provided some basic information about FTS and the link to the manual for more.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164019/3684)

#### Addressing your comment

> I am trying add this index it but gives me an error:
>
> ```
> ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
> ```

There are two variants of the function `to_tsvector()` - see ["function overloading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html)". The 1st takes only `text`, the 2nd takes `regconfig` and `text`. See for yourself:

```
SELECT proname, provolatile, proargtypes[0]::regtype, proargtypes[1]::regtype
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  proname = 'to_tsvector';
```

Only the second is `IMMUTABLE` and can be used in an index expression directly. *'simple'* in the above example is a text search configuration (`regconfig`).

**More importantly**, my oversight: `concat_ws()` (which I had in my first version) is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`. I added necessary steps above.

Related:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behavior of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573737/939860)
- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860)

Comment: I am trying add this index but give me error "ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE"

Comment: I check  “accent insensitive” so here is my select which I wrote : 
http://pastebin.com/y2ad1upn  ... Do you think is it ok? It works but this query runtime is about 800ms withou index. I've tried overload this function to_tsvector and use custom, but stll same issues. Can you give me example of index for my current select with accent insensitive? I'm sorry but I am totaly new in postgres. Thanks

Comment: @DenisStephanov: I had an oversight in my solution (sorry for the confusion!): `concat_ws()` is not `IMMUTABLE`. I added a solution and explanation above.

Comment: Concerning **`unaccent`**: You could integrate the function `unaccent()` ([the 2-parameter form like instructed here!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)) in `f_concat_ws()` and call it `f_unaccent_concat_ws()` or something. But you should always unaccent search arguments likewise to make it work! (And be aware of possible false matches due to the simplification.) The advanced solution would be to create a new text search configuration that uses the unaccent dictionary automatically. But that may be too advanced for you right now.

Comment: I use unaccent function in select in f_concat_ws() function and it works ! :) thanks for help :)

Comment: i know this is old but just wondering will the above search formula work for different combinations of the address? eg 22 Karntner Wien, Karntner Wien 22, Wien Karntner, etc ...

Comment: @rex: FTS allows both: to match single words (so the order of words in the search text is irrelevant) or phrase search (with a given order of words). There is an example in my answer.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time. THANKS! I was going to create a new column in the table to concatenate the fields I wanted, this idea of index just saved me a lot of work.

Comment: @lauksas: Either path has pros and cons. You *could* add that redundant column (ideally as [`GENERATED` column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279053/939860)). It makes index and bitmap index plan nodes a bit faster (but not index-only), because Postgres does not have repeat the concatenation to recheck an index condition in the heap tuple. But it adds overhead, write cost, and the table is bloated by the redundant column (long strings amplify the downside), which adds cost to everything else. It all depends ...

Comment: in my case @ErwinBrandstetter it just fits right, relatively big table (10GB) that get updated monthly by cron job, it is just perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: There's lots of great info in this answer, but it's quite focussed on the OP's specific problem, and zooms right in. I found [this](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/text-search-strategies-in-postgresql/) helpful to get an overview.

Answer (score 4):

Let's imagine this is your table and some data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    country text,
    city text,
    street text,
    house_number text,
    post_code text
) ;

INSERT INTO t
VALUES
   ('Österreich', 'Vienna', 'HauptStrasse', '123', '12345'),   
   ('France', 'Paris', 'Rue du Midi', '12A', '01234'),   
   ('España', 'Barcelona', 'Passeig de Gràcia', '32', '08001'),   
   ('United Kingdom', 'London', 'Oxford Street', '20', 'W1D 1AS'),
   ('Nederland', 'Amsterdam', 'Leidsekruisstraat', '6-8', '1017 RH') ;
```

[NOTE: **check it at** http://rextester.com/DOJN8533]

The way to perform a full text search to several columns using PostgreSQL (assuming 'english' is the name of your FTS configuration), is by using a query like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t
WHERE
    (
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(country, ''))      || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(city, ''))         || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(street, ''))       || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(house_number, '')) ||
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(post_code, '')) 
    ) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'Amsterdam') ;
```

The where clasuse means:

```
 (this tsvector = document) @@ /* matches */  (this tsquery = query)
```

A `tsvector` is a special data type used by PostgreSQL to store transformed data (for instance, all lowercased; with commas taken out, with words identified and listed, etc.) about a text. A `tsquery` is a way to *ask for* characteristics of a document (for instance *containing this _and_ that*).

The `||` operator combines tsvectors (let's say it "adds them together").

If you want to speed up things, you should have one functional index, defined like:

```
CREATE INDEX ts_idx 
    ON t USING gist ( 
    (
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(country, '')) || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(city, '')) || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(street, '')) || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(house_number, '')) ||
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(post_code, ''))
    ) 
) ;
```

You need to carefully check the documentation about [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html). It is a bit intimidating, because there are lots of possibilities, but it's worth spending the time.

To sort out results when there are many, you should use he `ts_rank` function to `ORDER BY` and then limit.

Comment: I have one more question .. is possible add to this fuzzy match? For example if I enter "Kyje", it will find Kyjev, Arkyjevlod, Kyjstron, and so on.  I try this example what you wrote, but it works only when I enter correct word which is in one of these columns

Comment: AFAIK full-text search cannot be used for fuzzy-search, although you can use different configurations (dictionaries) to have stemming (i.e. quick and quickly will be considered equivalent) and synonyms. If you want to look for *similarity* you can use *trigram indices* and *trigram similarity*. Look for [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html)

Comment: @DenisStephanov: FTS does support *prefix matching*, though. I added an answer.