# Optimize query with SIMILAR TO and many prefixes

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a query in PostgreSQL **9.6** that is taking a particularly long time to run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (gc.number)
       gc.number, gc.code, ch.client_id, ch.client_parent_id
FROM client gc, client_hierarchy ch
WHERE gc.code = ch.client_id
AND gc.number in (SELECT NUMB FROM directory
                  WHERE ACTIVE = TRUE
                  AND NUMB SIMILAR TO '(ABTR|GREW|POEW)%');
```

`SIMILAR TO` receives many different `NUMB`'s as parameter. `ABTR|GREW|POEW` and around 3.500 more.

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE directory (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    numb VARCHAR(8),
    branch VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(50),
    modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(200)
);
CREATE INDEX dir_numb_index ON directory (numb);
CREATE INDEX dir_branch_index ON bank_directory (branch);
CREATE INDEX dir_city_index ON bank_directory (city);
CREATE INDEX dir_name_index ON bank_directory (name);

CREATE TABLE client (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    number VARCHAR(8),
    code VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(200),
);
CREATE INDEX client_number_index ON client (number);
CREATE INDEX client_code_index ON client (code);
CREATE INDEX client_name_index ON client (name);

CREATE TABLE client_hierarchy (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    client_id VARCHAR(9),
    client_parent_id VARCHAR(9),
    modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX client_id_hierarchy_index ON client_hierarchy (client_id);
CREATE INDEX client_parent_id_hierarchy_index ON client_hierarchy (client_parent_id);
```

Table `client` has 5K rows and `client_hierarchy` 900K rows.

Output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Unique  (cost=21869.20..21890.98 rows=3760 width=23) (actual time=3117.734..3118.110 rows=707 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7786
  ->  Sort  (cost=21869.20..21880.09 rows=4357 width=23) (actual time=3117.733..3117.869 rows=998 loops=1)
        Sort Key: gc.number
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 102kB
        Buffers: shared hit=7786
        ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1179.86..21605.84 rows=4357 width=23) (actual time=2825.705..3115.586 rows=998 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((gc.number)::text = (directory.numb)::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=7786
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=158.03..20524.10 rows=4357 width=23) (actual time=2.101..311.200 rows=3777 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((ch.client_id)::text = (gc.code)::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=7280
                    ->  Seq Scan on client_hierarchy ch  (cost=0.00..15955.00 rows=873500 width=10) (actual time=0.008..161.576 rows=873349 loops=1)
                          Filter: active
                          Buffers: shared hit=7220
                    ->  Hash  (cost=103.57..103.57 rows=4357 width=13) (actual time=1.969..1.969 rows=4391 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 262kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=60
                          ->  Seq Scan on gbo_client gc  (cost=0.00..103.57 rows=4357 width=13) (actual time=0.004..1.016 rows=4391 loops=1)
                                Filter: active
                                Buffers: shared hit=60
              ->  Hash  (cost=953.95..953.95 rows=5430 width=9) (actual time=2803.112..2803.112 rows=5563 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 287kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=506
                    ->  Seq Scan on directory  (cost=0.00..953.95 rows=5430 width=9) (actual time=1.353..2800.528 rows=5563 loops=1)
                          Filter: (active AND ((numb)::text ~ '^(?:(?:AACM|AACO).*)$'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 30318
                          Buffers: shared hit=506
Planning time: 8.529 ms
Execution time: 3118.224 ms
```

It is not necessary to guarantee order, just need remove duplicated rows with `DISTINCT ON`, because is the same client...they are dirty data.

Is it possible to optimize this?

#### SOLUTION

Base on feedback here, my new query:

```
SELECT client.numb, client.code, ch.client_id, ch.client_parent_id
 FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (gc.number) gc.number, gc.code
      FROM client gc
      WHERE EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM client_hierarchy ch
                    WHERE ch.client_id = gc.code
                    )
      AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM bank_directory
                    WHERE active AND numb = gc.number
      )
      AND numb ~ '^(?:AACM|AACO)'
      ) as client
 INNER JOIN client_hierarchy ch ON client.code = ch.client_id;
```

New `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=11080.16..20448.74 rows=1251 width=23) (actual time=368.303..373.574 rows=707 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=8236
  ->  Unique  (cost=11079.73..11086.15 rows=1251 width=13) (actual time=368.286..368.684 rows=707 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=5402
        ->  Sort  (cost=11079.73..11082.94 rows=1284 width=13) (actual time=368.285..368.410 rows=998 loops=1)
              Sort Key: gc.number
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 71kB
              Buffers: shared hit=5402
              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1312.74..11013.44 rows=1284 width=13) (actual time=19.826..366.642 rows=998 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((gc.number)::text = (directory.numb)::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=5402
                    ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.42..9683.47 rows=1284 width=13) (actual time=0.987..346.895 rows=1070 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=4896
                          ->  Seq Scan on client gc  (cost=0.00..114.46 rows=1284 width=13) (actual time=0.857..327.979 rows=1252 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((numb)::text ~ '^(?:AACM|AACO)'::text)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3139
                                Buffers: shared hit=60
                          ->  Index Only Scan using client_id_hierarchy_index on client_hierarchy ch_1  (cost=0.42..7.44 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1252)
                                Index Cond: (client_id = (gc.code)::text)
                                Heap Fetches: 1070
                                Buffers: shared hit=4836
                    ->  Hash  (cost=864.36..864.36 rows=35836 width=9) (actual time=18.790..18.790 rows=35881 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1949kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=506
                          ->  Seq Scan on directory  (cost=0.00..864.36 rows=35836 width=9) (actual time=0.010..11.200 rows=35881 loops=1)
                                Filter: active
                                Buffers: shared hit=506
  ->  Index Scan using client_id_hierarchy_index on client_hierarchy ch  (cost=0.42..7.46 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=707)
        Index Cond: ((client_id)::text = (gc.code)::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=2834
Planning time: 63.201 ms
Execution time: 373.721 ms
```

Now I get results in 300-400ms. Down from 3,5 seconds.

Comment: The `Filter: active` below the `Seq Scan on client_hierarchy ch` and the other one below the `Seq Scan on client gc`  do not seem to correspond to anything in your query?

Comment: This is true, but I do not why...I do simple join in where with this tables

Comment: You provided some useful information, but more is required for performance questions. In particular the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, not just `EXPLAIN` and table definitions (valid `CREATE TABLE` scripts. Follow instruction in the [postgresql-performance] tag. Also please clarify this cryptic statement: `SIMILAR TO receive many different prefix (3k+).`

Comment: Also: you use `DISTINCT ON` without `ORDER BY`. Do you care *which* row from `client_hierarchy` is appended if there is more than one match. And cardinalities for `directory` are missing.

Comment: It looks as if `client` is not a table but a view applying a `WHERE active=true` condition on top of another table, which would be why a seq scan is used and the index ignored. Same thing for `client_hierarchy`. Also your DDL for `client` is missing a `number` column that is used in the query.

Comment: Your performance comparison seems off, since the second query only has two prefix strings while the first has three. Also, the query is invalid, the predicate `AND numb ~ '^(?:AACM|AACO)'` is impossible where you put it. More importantly, you are probably testing the wrong thing here, your actual query has  3.5k strings. Whole different story. Cardinalities for `directory` (`bank_directory`?) are still missing. How many rows, how many of then "active"?

Comment: Explain plan in the solution is from query that I have executed with 3,5K strings in the predicate and is pretty fast (400ms). All rows is "active" in this table.

Answer (score 1):

We don't actually have the selectivity and costs of the query to optimize this. You need to `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as mentioned in the comments. That said, a few points..

- `WHERE ACTIVE = TRUE` is triggering a seq scan (you can also just say `WHERE active` for clarity). You can add an index on active which may produce a faster result.
- You can rewrite the query, to use `EXISTS` which may be faster depending on how `numb` are returned from the inner query.
- Depending on the domain of `numb`, that may be a suitable to be turned into an `enum` which is faster.
- You call `DISTINCT ON`. You may find it faster to do two exist tests here..

like this

```
SELECT gc.number, gc.code, ch.client_id, ch.client_parent_id
FROM client gc
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM client_hierarchy ch
  WHERE ch.client_id = gc.code
)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM directory
  WHERE active
    AND numb = gc.number
    AND numb SIMILAR TO '(ABTR|GREW|POEW)%'
);
```

Also, it becomes clear when written like this that this is awkward and can be pushed down..

```
    AND numb = gc.number
    AND numb SIMILAR TO '(ABTR|GREW|POEW)%'
```

into this..

```
SELECT gc.number, gc.code, ch.client_id, ch.client_parent_id
FROM client gc
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM client_hierarchy ch
  WHERE ch.client_id = gc.code
)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM directory
  WHERE active
    AND numb = gc.number
)
AND number SIMILAR TO '(ABTR|GREW|POEW)%';
```

Lastly `SIMILAR TO` should probably never be used. See this [awesome post by Erwin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/2639) for more information.

Comment: Seems like you removed too much. `SELECT  .. ch.client_id ...` requires `client_hierarchy ch` in the `FROM` list. Also, if `directory <-> client` is a 1:n relationship, it should be beneficial to do the more expensive pattern matching on the (presumably) smaller table `directory` (only based on my educated guess).

Comment: Thanks Evan, just missing add INNER JOIN with table client_hierarchy and works much better. I have modified my post with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a few assumptions, this should be ***substantially*** faster:

```
SELECT c.number, c.code, h.client_id, h.client_parent_id
FROM   directory d
JOIN   client    c ON c.number = d.numb
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT client_id, client_parent_id
   FROM   client_hierarchy
   WHERE  client_id = c.code
-- ORDER  BY ???  -- to decide which row is picked
   LIMIT  1
   ) h
WHERE  d.active  -- same as d.active = TRUE
AND    d.numb ~ '^(?:ABTR|GREW|POEW)';
```

Assuming you only need `DISTINCT ON` because there can be multiple matches in `client_hierarchy` and not for any other reason.

Never use `SIMILAR TO`. I replaced it with an equivalent regular expression. Rationale:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

The rewritten query can use an index on `client_hierarchy` efficiently (which you already have):

```
CREATE INDEX ON client_hierarchy (client_id);
```

If you add `ORDER BY`, make the index match! If you can get index-only scans out of it, you might *append* the two small payload columns to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON client_hierarchy (client_id, client_id, client_parent_id)
```

Detailed explanation (in particular the leading section on indexes and chapter 2a):

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

I also rewrote the `IN (<query>)` construct to a plain join. Typically faster and equivalent (unless you fold duplicates with `IN`, which I assume is not the case). A partial index on `directory` *might* pay. Not enough information in the question ...

If `directory` has many rows, one of these 3 index options may be best:

- A `text_pattern_ops` index to support prefix matching:

  - [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)
- A trigram index:

  - [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)
- A full text index on a `tsvector` column or expression. See:

  - [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column/157982#157982)
  - [PostgreSQL full text search on many columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164000/postgresql-full-text-search-on-many-columns/164081#164081)

If you have many different prefixes in the `WHERE` clause and not so many rows in `directory`, it may well be you do not need *any* index on that table because a sequential scan is faster.

#### Your added solution

If the `EXISTS` semi-join works for you, remove the duplicated filter and make it a legal query:

```
SELECT c.number, c.code, h.client_id, h.client_parent_id
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (gc.number) gc.number, gc.code
   FROM   client gc
   WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM bank_directory
      WHERE  active
      AND    numb ~ '^(?:AACM|AACO)'
      AND    numb = gc.number
      )
   ) c
JOIN   client_hierarchy h ON h.client_id = c.code;
```

Still odd that you seem to be happy with an *arbitrary* `gc.code` from each set of dupes.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, awesome post!! Is very useful for me, because I have little experience in database.

Comment: That's quite a post there, @ErwinBrandstetter.